# GTM (Google Tag Manager) 6.0 and Firebase Analytics 5.0 version conflict

Tags: swift, cocoapods, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, xcode9.3

New Firebase version 5.0 is causing version conflict with Google Tag Manager. Has anyone has a solution for this?

**Podfile:**

```
# Analytics
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 6.0'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2.7.0'
```

**Error** i get on **pod install**:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAnalytics":
  In Podfile:

Firebase/Core (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.0.0)

Firebase/RemoteConfig (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  FirebaseRemoteConfig (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
    FirebaseAnalytics (~> 5.0)

GoogleTagManager (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
  FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
```

Comment: Looks like Google didn't update the Tag Manager pod when Firebase 5.0 came out. There's a [ticket](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/q5RYBvAdqKI;context-place=forum/tag-manager) in the official help forum that would probably help if we star/reply to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At last Google Released Google Tag Manager Pod version 7.0.0 and this problem is solved

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** This issue is resolved in GoogleTagManager 7.0.0.

**Obsolete answer**: Seems like there are no backwards-incompatible changes in Firebase Analytics 5.x and major version bump is due to drop of iOS 7 support.
It's not an issue for my project, so I just created patched podspec for GoogleTagManager.

**GoogleTagManager.podspec.json**

```
{
  "authors": "Google, Inc.",
  "dependencies": {
    "FirebaseAnalytics": "~> 5.0",
    "GoogleAnalytics": "~> 3.17",
    "GoogleUtilities": "~> 1.3"
  },
  "description": "Google Tag Manager is a tool to easily deploy analytics and marketing tags.",
  "frameworks": [
    "AdSupport",
    "CoreTelephony",
    "JavaScriptCore",
    "SystemConfiguration",
    "UIKit"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://www.google.com/tagmanager",
  "libraries": [
    "sqlite3",
    "z"
  ],
  "license": {
    "text": "Copyright 2017 Google",
    "type": "Copyright"
  },
  "name": "GoogleTagManager",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "7.0"
  },
  "resources": [
    "Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/Resources/TagManagerResources.bundle"
  ],
  "source": {
    "http": "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/07041f585a34f209/GoogleTagManager-6.0.0.tar.gz"
  },
  "summary": "Google Tag Manager - create and update tags easily",
  "vendored_frameworks": [
    "Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework"
  ],
  "version": "6.0.0"
}
```

**Podfile**

```
pod 'GoogleTagManager', podspec: './GoogleTagManager.podspec.json'
```

Comment: Since Google team does not give a s..t about the issue; best way is to override on our own. Thanks for the solution